# Optimize sql query for pagination

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

What can I do to make my code faster for paging.?
I tried putting it in a Temporary table.
The problem was Creating the temporary table took 4.56 seconds.
The number of rows in `wp_bp_xprofile_data` is almost 25k only. I don't know why it would take to much time just for that.

Also when do I know when the was connection is closed. Is It every page refresh?

```
//
            //all variable are processed here....
            //

    $sql = "SELECT
          DN.User_ID,
          case when (FN.user_id is null or (length( trim( FN.meta_value )) = 0)) 
               and  (LN.user_id is null or (length( trim( LN.meta_value )) = 0)) then DN.value  
               else trim(concat( FN.meta_value, ' ', LN.meta_value )) end as Name,
          DN.Value DisplayName, 
          COALESCE( G.Value, '' ) Gender,
          COALESCE( BD.Value, '' ) Birthday,
          COALESCE( FLOOR( DATEDIFF( CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE( BD.value,'%m/%d/%Y'))/365), '' ) Age,
          COALESCE( P.Value, '' ) Phone,
          COALESCE( E.Value, '' ) Email,
          COALESCE( O.Value, '' ) Occupation, 
          COALESCE( R.Value, '' ) Region,
          COALESCE( PR.Value, '' ) Province,
          COALESCE( C.Value, '' ) City,
          COALESCE( CC.Value, '' ) CurrentCountry  
    FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data DN 
             LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data G 
                ON DN.User_ID = G.User_ID AND G.field_id = 270 
             LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data BD 
                ON DN.User_ID = BD.User_ID AND BD.field_id = 274 
             LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data P 
                ON DN.User_ID = P.User_ID AND P.field_id = 275 
             LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data E 
                ON DN.User_ID = E.User_ID AND E.field_id = 286 
             LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data O 
                ON DN.User_ID = O.User_ID AND O.field_id = 71 
             LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data CC
                ON DN.User_ID = CC.User_ID AND CC.field_id = 73 
             LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data R
                ON DN.User_ID = R.User_ID AND R.field_id = 24 
             LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data PR
                ON DN.User_ID = PR.User_ID AND PR.field_id = 355 
             LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data C
                ON DN.User_ID = C.User_ID AND C.field_id = 354
             LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta FN
                ON DN.User_ID = FN.User_ID AND FN.meta_key = 'first_name'
             LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta LN
                ON DN.User_ID = LN.User_ID AND LN.meta_key = 'last_name'
    where DN.field_id = 1  ";

    if(!empty($_region))
    {
        $sql .= " AND R.User_ID IS NOT NULL AND R.Value = '".$_region."' ";
    }
    if(!empty($_province))
    {
        $sql .= " AND PR.User_ID IS NOT NULL AND PR.Value LIKE '".$_province."%' ";
    }
    if(!empty($_city))
    { 
        $sql .= " AND C.user_id IS NOT NULL AND C.Value LIKE '".$_city."%' ";
    }
    if(!empty($_ageMin) && !empty($_ageMax))
    {
        $sql .= " AND BD.User_ID IS NOT NULL AND FLOOR( DATEDIFF( CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE( BD.value,'%m/%d/%Y'))/365) BETWEEN   ".$_ageMin."  AND  ".$_ageMax;
    }
    if(!empty($_occupation))
    { 
        $sql .= " AND O.User_ID  IS NOT NULL AND O.Value = '".$_occupation."' ";
    }
    if(!empty($_gender))
    { 
        $sql .= " AND G.User_ID IS NOT NULL AND G.Value = '".$_gender."' ";
    } 
    if(!empty($_country))
    { 
        $sql .= " AND CC.User_ID IS NOT NULL AND CC.Value = '".$_country."' ";
    }  

    if(isset($search_val)){
        $sql .= "  
            AND
            (FN.meta_value LIKE '%".$search_val."%' OR  
            LN.meta_value LIKE '%".$search_val."%' OR 
            E.Value LIKE '%".$search_val."%' OR 
            O.Value LIKE '%".$search_val."%' OR 
            R.Value LIKE '%".$search_val."%' OR
            PR.Value LIKE '%".$search_val."%' OR
            C.Value LIKE '%".$search_val."%' OR
            CC.Value LIKE '%".$search_val."%')
        ";
    }

    $maxRow = $wpdb->getResults($sql);
    $limit = 30;
    $maxPage = ceil($maxRow/$limit); 

    if(!empty($page)){
        $start = ($limit * $page) - $limit; 
    }else{
        $start = 0; 
    }

    Generate_Pagination($maxRow);

    $sql .= " LIMIT ".$start." , ".$limit; 

    $datas = $wpdb->getResults($sql);

    foreach($data as $data){
        //output data;
    }
    ?>
```

Using `Explain`

[image]

When removing this code

> FN.meta_value LIKE '%".$search_val."%' OR
>        LN.meta_value LIKE '%".$search_val."%' Or

Would Speed up the query. `wp_usermeta` has 300k rows.
also has different `meta_key`

table    `wp_usermeta`

```
     ` umeta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value`
```

Comment: can you run an explain on this query?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

```
    $sql = 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ... LIMIT ' . $limit;

    $rows = $this->_db->fetchAll($sql);                                                                    
    $data = array(                                                                                         
        "total" => $this->_db->fetchOne('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()'),             
        "rows" => $rows                                                                                    
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are issuing a

```
 $maxRow = $wpdb->getResults($sql);
```

before attaching a `LIMIT` with `OFFSET`. This will result in fetching many more records than what you need for pagination.

You are issuing this

```
$datas = $wpdb->getResults($sql);
```

after attaching a `LIMIT`, which is fine.

You should eliminate the first `getResults` call and your performance will improve.

Comment: but the purpose of that is to generate a paging like `Prev | 2 | 3 | 4 | Next`

Comment: That is done using your second `getResults`. not the first one. I think the purpose of the first `getResults` is just to get the row count. If that is true, then I feel there are better ways to get row count. And Please use the correct terminology. `Paging` is different from `Pagination`. What you want is `Pagination`.

Comment: Note that you don't need row count for `pagination` to work. You need it only to calculate **total number of pages**. And usually you will not show links for all the pages since they may not fit on one row. All you need to know is if there is one more page after the current page, so that you can either enable or disable the `Next` link.

Comment: Also `COUNT(*)` will be more efficient than selecting columns to get row count.

Comment: How about something like `page 1 of 43` ?

Comment: If you must display page count, use `COUNT(*)`. Fine tune the indexes so that `COUNT(*)` does not result in too much I/O. `SELECT`ing column is expensive because MySQL has to actually fetch the data from disk. `COUNT(*)` allows MySQL to use any optimal technique it can, to get you the count. Sometimes this can be done just by scanning the indexes. Hence `COUNT(*)` is often more efficient.

Comment: i tried count but its still the same :'( just a little improvement

Comment: run `EXPLAIN` on your query to see exactly what is happening. May be you need to tune indexes

Comment: sorry but i don't know what is `explain` output. i tried it and updated my questions

Comment: Look under `rows` column of the output. If the number is large, there is scope for improvement. Your output shows 10986 rows were fetched from `DN` table, which seems to be your problem. You should optimize to reduce that number. I also think you did not run `EXPLAIN` on the full query (with all the `AND`s and `LIMIT` etc.). To get a true picture, run `EXPLAIN` on the final query.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is the search.

You use '%...%' which prevents the use of simple indexes. This means the entire table has to be checked for those. Some database systems are capable of indexing for such searches (Postgresql has such a feature) but you need to some quite advanced setup to get such to work quickly.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-debugging.html

MySQL probably has something equivalent.

This being said, in most cases you can reduce the set of rows by placing the tests that do not use the '%...' first in the WHERE clause. It already looks like you're doing so, but I did not look in detail: if you are using a pattern against a different table, for example, the WHERE would still be slow.

Also, all those tests that appear before the '%...' should be against columns that have an index if you want speed at the time you do a SELECT (there is a trade off between having indexes and doing a lot of INSERT INTO rather than a lot of SELECT.)